# Gwt GooglePicker not getting a result

Tags: java, gwt, google-picker

Warning 2 part Question:
I am using [Gwt Google Picker](https://github.com/komasoftware/gwt-google-picker) in an app.

1. While trying to get the result back I am hitting an error here is my code:

   ```
   private final static String appId = "ViDemantay";
   private final static AppUser appUser = GWT.create(AppUser.class);
   private static HandlesMedia handler;
   private static GooglePickerCell pickerCell;
   private final static AbstractPickerCallback callback = new AbstractPickerCallback(){



       @Override
       public void onCanceled() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

       @Override
       public void onPicked(ViewToken viewToken, BaseResult result) {
           $.console.log(result);
           DocumentResult docs = result.<DocumentResult>cast();
           String mediaUrl = docs.getDocs().get(0).getEmbedUrl();
           String thumbnail = docs.getDocs().get(0).getThumbnails().get(0).getUrl();
           handler.setMediaUrl(thumbnail);
           handler.setMediaUrl(mediaUrl);
           $.console.log("The handler is " + handler);
           pickerCell.setValue(null, null, handler);


       }}; ///////////end callback////////////////////////////

       private static  Picker picker;

       public static void get(){PickerLoader.loadApi(apiKey, new Runnable(){

           @Override
           public void run() {

               appUser.load($(window).prop("appUser"));
               picker = PickerBuilder.create().addCallback(callback).setAppId(appId)
                       .setAuthUser(appUser.getAcctId()).setOAuthToken(appUser.getAuthToken())
                       .addView(ViewId.DOCS).addView(ViewId.YOUTUBE)
                       .hideTitleBar().build();
               picker.setVisible(false);
           }});}
   ```

It would seem that the callback is never called back instead on the browser's console I get this error:

```
TypeError: this$static_0_g$ is undefined
```

This is what is executed after a file is picked ... but no result.

2. I am trying to use the Picker inside a Gwt data grid.  I have tried to create a GooglePickerCell but alas , I am having a wee bit trouble getting things working.   Has anyone already implemented  something like this? would love to see some wiring.   Here's what I've done:  On second thought this post is already long enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was that my  callback was final and static . Once I changed it two an anonymous class all was gravy:
should be

```
picker = PickerBuilder.create().addCallback( new AbstractPickerCallback(){



@Override
public void onCanceled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPicked(ViewToken viewToken, BaseResult result) {
    $.console.log(result);
    DocumentResult docs = result.<DocumentResult>cast();
    String mediaUrl = docs.getDocs().get(0).getEmbedUrl();
    String thumbnail = docs.getDocs().get(0).getThumbnails().get(0).getUrl();
    handler.setMediaUrl(thumbnail);
    handler.setMediaUrl(mediaUrl);
    $.console.log("The handler is " + handler);
    pickerCell.setValue(null, null, handler);


}})
.setAppId(appId)
                .setAuthUser(appUser.getAcctId()).setOAuthToken(appUser.getAuthToken())
                .addView(ViewId.DOCS).addView(ViewId.YOUTUBE)
                .hideTitleBar().build();
        picker.setVisible(false);
```

So now the result is back... mental note always check for null on the result url or thumbnails.

As far as part two is concerned , Ill be looking into EditableCell implementation because the cell value was changed but the client wasn't updated.